# Make datestamp for status updates show time

Tags: date, timestamp

I have an installation of Wordpress 3.6 running on my server. Playing around with it, I found that 'status updates' don't show the time posted:

[image]

Here's the thing: I want the time there too. Something like this would be best:

[image]

Is there a way to change the format the time is shown in? Something in a child theme?

Answer (score 0):

Just go to <kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>General</kbd>, scroll down to the **date formatting** section, select **custom**, and type this:

```
F jS, g:i a
```

which yields a date like:

```
June 1st, 7:29 pm
```

The [official WordPress docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time) give the letters to use for time formatting.